# Donation at good place with certain mentioned intention accumulates good karma?

Tags: belief, karma

As we all know , Donation at sattvika place (having guarantee that our donation will get use for good cause ) is a good karma.

But what if we donate with the intension -

"Hey god, I am donating this as a donation is good karma , I am ready to accept whatever you give."

```
1. Does good karma get accumulate in this case?

2. Is this a kind of Rajasi but good karma?

3. Does doner will get good results through this?
```

Comment: I was also about to refer 17.20-22, which is already mentioned in @SwamiVishwananda's [answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8457/1049) below. But I feel that the main 3 questions are not answered directly, instead they are left on the one's discretion. IMO, (1) Yes, Karma does get accumulated in this case and mostly likely to be good karma as it's donated at Sattvik place (2) Yes, it's termed as Rajasi, because it's done with certain intention (to get favor back). Here the intention is to accumulate good karma. (3) Yes, usually fruits will be temporary even though pleasing to senses.

Comment: @iammilind pleasing to senses means?

Comment: "Pleasing to senses" means something which is enjoyed by our 5 worldly senses. Rajasic things are done for sensual pleasures. I am not commenting it as right/wrong, but just describing what it is according to my understanding of Gita.

Comment: @iammilind what is the use of mukti? what happenes after mukti? what we do in that phase? ( I know mukti is escape from birth and death) but what exactly happens to us in that case? do we go into heaven for enjoyment?

Comment: What you ask is probably a good and different question. From my knowledge, *Mukti* is merging the *Atma* into *Param-Atma*. The *Atma* is a part of God and is statutory inside every body, but is attached to *Jeeva*. *Mukti* will detach the *Atma* from that *Jeeva* or Life-Death cycle. One can derive *Anand* from *Sukh/Happiness* and even *Dukh/Sorrow*. This *Sukh* and *Dukh* are related to *Heaven* and *Hell*. But *Mukti* is beyond them and results in *Param-Anand*. *Mukti* and *Moksha* are used interchangeably. What I wrote is my limited understanding from limited scriptures & internet.

Comment: @iammilind actually it is indirectly related , since selfless donation will lead a person to mukti..

Comment: @Sagar You may be interested in my question here about different types of liberation: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6943/36 And my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6686/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8459/does-holy-name-chanting-while-doing-wordly-duties-give-punnya-karma  can you please answer this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sri Krishna says in the Gita that there are three kinds of giving when He defines the different types of sacrifices, austerities, and gifts. He details this in Chapter 17 verses 7-28. All the verses should be read. A few of the verses are as follows:

> verse 7. Even the food that is dear to all is of three kinds. Likewise are the sacrifices, austerities, and gifts. Hear now of the distinction between them.
>
> verse 20. That gift which is made to one who can make no return, and with the feeling that it is one's duty to give, and which is given at the right place and time to a worthy person--such a gift is held to be of the nature of sattva.
>
> verse 21. But that which is given for the sake of recompense or with the expectation of fruit or in a grudging mood is accounted as of the nature of rajas.
>
> verse 22. And the gift which is made without respect or with disdain, at an improper place and time, and to an unworthy person is declared to be of the nature of tamas.

In verses 23-27 The Lord says why acts of sacrifice, austerity, and gifts are always begun by saying "Om" and the meaning of "Om Tat Sat" when doing these actions.

and finally:

> verse 28. Whatever sacrifice or gift is made, whatever austerity is practiced, whatever ceremony is observed--it is all called "asat," "unreal," if it is done without faith. It is of no account here or hereafter.